# Capture global touch events (Symbian)

Tags: python, symbian, nokia, s60, pys60

Basically I wanted what the pys60 module `keycapture` does (global capture of keystrokes) but I wanted to do this with the touchscreen. So if the program is running, all touch events can be intercepted and logged by the program. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if I understand, but I am witnessing a plug-in kind of touch-screen interceptor that uses FEP (Front End Processor). This way some people override standard touch-screen keyboard.

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=S60+Front+End+Processor&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=